# how to kill specific wine window handle

Tags: wine

```
winedbg --command 'info wnd'
Window handle        Class Name        Style    WndProc          Thread   Text
00010020             #32769            96000000 0000000000000000 00000080 -- Empty --
 (...)
 0001005c            EVA_Window_Dblclk 960f0000 0000000000000000 00000108 kakaotalk
  (...)
  000100f8           BannerAdWnd       52000000 0000000000000000 00000108 -- Empty --
```

my goal is to close an ad by its window handle, `000100f8`. however, I was unable to find any information.

- xkill will fail because since window handle is part of another window (also doesn't show up on `wmctrl -l`)

```
xkill -id 000100f8
xkill:  killing creator of resource 0x40
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  113 (X_KillClient)
  Value in failed request:  0x40
  Serial number of failed request:  8
  Current serial number in output stream:  9
```

- [winedbg only shows window info](https://linux.die.net/man/1/winedbg), not a way to manipulate them

Comment: I'm afraid your only option is win32 or wpf api programming and building portable exe under windows os which you could later test using wine prefix =)

Comment: or if your unwanted window has a dedicated process id (but I don't think so xD) check it via `winedbg --command 'info process'` then you're lucky and you could kill it using `echo "taskkill /f /pid 666whateverpid` or `echo "taskkill /f /im ProcessName.exe" | wine cmd.exe -c`

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to resolve your initial problem is simply restricting that IPs & domains (in `/etc/hosts`) from where you receive advertisements ... so [trace network activity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375402/236391) of that "kakaotalk" app and try to eliminate advs